Как в функции save_file достать переменную file_Path, open_file из функции open_file?
вот код:
import customtkinter
from tkinter import filedialog

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("light")

class App_class(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self, root_tk=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("1000x600")
        self.title("Текстовый редактор")

        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=0)

        self.textbox = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(self, width=1000, height=600)
        self.textbox.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 0, pady = 0)

        self.button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="открыть файл",command=self.open_file, width=100, height=40)
        self.button.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)

        self.button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="Сохранить",command=self.save_file, width=100, height=40)
        self.button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)


    def open_file(self):
        file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Выберите файл")
        if file_path:
            try:
                with open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as open_files:
                    content = open_files.read()
                self.textbox.delete("1.0", "end")
                self.textbox.insert("1.0", content)

            except Exception as e:
                self.textbox.delete('1.0', 'end')
                self.textbox.insert('1.0', "Не удалось прочитать файл.")

    def save_file(self):
        from file_path

        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App_class()
    app.mainloop()


Добавить их в self. ‍♀️

В функции open_file запоминаешь переменную open_files:
self.open_files = open_files, а в функции save_file вспоминаешь её:
open_files = self.open_files. Итоговый код:
import customtkinter
from tkinter import filedialog

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("light")

class App_class(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self, root_tk=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("1000x600")
        self.title("Текстовый редактор")

        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=0)

        self.textbox = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(self, width=1000, height=600)
        self.textbox.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 0, pady = 0)

        self.button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="открыть файл",command=self.open_file, width=100, height=40)
        self.button.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)

        self.button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="Сохранить",command=self.save_file, width=100, height=40)
        self.button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)


    def open_file(self):
        file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Выберите файл")
        if file_path:
            try:
                with open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as open_files:
                    self.open_files = open_files
                    content = open_files.read()
                self.textbox.delete("1.0", "end")
                self.textbox.insert("1.0", content)

            except Exception as e:
                self.textbox.delete("1.0", "1.0")
                self.textbox.insert("1.0", "Не удалось прочитать файл.")

    def save_file(self):
        open_files = self.open_files
        # Сохраняешь open_files
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App_class()
    app.mainloop()

